# Cómo asignar ruta por variable o por argumento a través de la URL?

Tags: python, url, flask

Quiero mantener el mismo esquema URL a través del árbol de páginas de forma que no tenga que mandar al usuario a otra ruta para después volver a la misma una rama más profunda.

Ejemplo:

Tenemos la raiz -> http://dominio.com y tenemos otra página con una lista de enlaces http://dominio.com/lista

Si navegamos a uno de esos elementos de la lista nos manda a otra rama inferior pero tiene tantos elementos que la hemos "paginado" y nos manda por defecto a la página 1 por lo que la url sería

```
http://dominio.com/lista/elemento_x/1
```

Si dentro de esa nueva lista paginada de enlaces navegamos nuevamente a otro elemento inferior y queremos mantener la ruta añadiendo la nueva rama quedaría así:

```
http://dominio.com/lista/elemento_x/1/elemento_z
```

Resulta incómodo (y no sé hasta que punto SEO compatible) tener el numero de la página a mitad de ruta. Imagina que tu lista engorda y el `elemento_z` ya no está en la página 1 sino en la 3. Si guardaste esa ruta anterior o lo hizo Google, deja de ser válido. O si intentas acceder a `/lista/elemento_x/elemento_z` te fallará también porque `elemento_z` no es un numero de página válido.

¿Cómo solucionar esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask tiene previsto esto y te permite libertad a la hora de acceder a las variables y/o argumentos cuando accedes a las rutas que defines.

Por ejemplo:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/arg')
def estatica():
    argumento = request.args.get('argumento',type=str, default=None)
    return f"{argumento}"

@app.route('/arg/<variable>')
def variable(variable=None):
    return f"{variable}"
```

Verás que hemos definido tres rutas, la raiz "/", y dos rutas `estatica()` y `variable(variable=None)`

Si accedes a `/arg/ejemplo` en el navegador te aparecerá en la página la palabra `ejemplo`, porque hemos definido la ruta como `/arg/<variable>` y todo lo que esté dentro de `<variable>` se le pasa a la función.

Si accedes a `/arg?argumento=ejemplo` en el navegador te aparecerá también la palabra `ejemplo` pero en este caso no hemos modificado la ruta y hemos pasado la palabra como un argumento con `?argumento=`. En este caso hemos usado el método `request` de flask para obtener el argumento (o varios si quieres) por el nombre.

Esto soluciona el problema de la pregunta de respetar la ruta a través de un árbol de páginas si alguna está paginada.

Esto es:

```
http://dominio.com/lista/elemento_x?pagina=3
```

puede contener un enlace a:

```
http://dominio.com/lista/elemento_x/elemento_z
```

sin problema.

De esta forma tenemos la misma ruta con dos funciones distintas tanto por argumento como por variable.